# Why are Meteor Router functions always being run twice

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I'm using the Router package from meteorite.

```
Meteor.Router.add
  "/article/:id": ->
    log "article"
    "article"
```

Whenever the article page/template gets loaded, the callback function in the Router always gets run twice. I'm trying to use the callback function for incrementing the view count of the articles. So this poses a problem (every inc is done twice).

Is this the intended behavior? Or did I do something wrong?

**UPDATE**

It's actually not always being run twice. It happens when the page is refreshed or for the first time the browser navigates to the page. Regardless, it still poses a problem.

Comment: This isn't the intended behavior afaik, How do you load each article's url? is it via a `Meteor.Router.to`? or a url?

Comment: I'm using the provided Helper {{renderPage}} inside the main html file that contains the <body> tag. And the article page is loaded with contents inside the respective template.

Comment: I mean when you load `/article/1` in your browser do you use a `<a href='/article/1'>` to load the page or `Meteor.Router.to('/article/1')`?

Comment: Yes <a href='/article/1'>. I just found that the page.js context object differs slightly for each of the 2 calls. First has init set to true. The 2nd one has it undefined.

Comment: Also, it's actually not always being run twice. It happens when the page is refreshed or for the first time the browser navigates to the page. Regardless, it still poses a problem.

Comment: I've made a blank project with the router, and tried on a refresh or first load @ https://gist.github.com/Tarangp/5085008 but I can't replicate this

Comment: Okay found the culprit. I'm using the HTML5-History-API package for IE 8+ routing support. Your gist runs fine without it, but will run into the same problem when HTML5-History-API is added. +1 to you for helping me to find the reason!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The culprit is the HTML5-History-API package I'm using for IE 8+ routing support. The solution below will serve to help people with the same setup and problem.

---

Found a solution. But I'm not sure if this is the intended way for handling this.

```
"/article/:id": (id) ->
   unless this.init
     Session.set "articleId", id
     Meteor.call "incArticleViews", id
   "article"
```

If there's a better solution, please post it and I'll accept.

Comment: This doesn't always work in FF, but it prevents the double hit in Chrome.